# How to I split the time_taken' column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror, duration, timedelta

I am trying to split the time_taken attribute (eg., 02h 10m) into only numbers using the below code.
I have checked earlier posts and this code seemed to work fine for some of you but it is not working for me.

```
t=pd.to_timedelta(df3['time_taken'])
df3['hours']=t.dt.components['hours']
df3['minutes']=t.dt.components['minutes']
df3.head()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid unit abbreviation: hm
```

I am unable to understand the error. Can anyone help me split the column into hours and mins? It would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: make simple example for answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code. Since you mentioned that your **time_taken** attribute looks like this: **02h 10m**. I have written an example code which you can try out.

```
import pandas as pd

# initializing example time data
time_taken = ['1h 10m', '2h 20m', '3h 30m', '4h 40m', '5h 50m']

#inserting the time data into a pandas DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame(time_taken, columns = ['time_taken'])

# see how the data looks like
print(data)

# initializing "Hours" and "Minutes" columns"
# and assigning the value 0 to both for now.
data['Hours'] = 0
data['Minutes'] = 0

# when I ran this code, the data type for the elements 
# in time_taken column was numpy.int64
# so we convert it into string type

data['time_taken'] = data['time_taken'].apply(str)

# loop through the elements to split into Hours and minutes
for i in range(len(data)):
    temp = data.iat[i,0]
    hours, minutes = temp.split() # use python .split() function for strings
    data.iat[i,1] = hours.translate({ord('h'): None})
    data.iat[i,2] = minutes.translate({ord('m'): None})


# the correct data is here
print(data)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. However, I want to create two separate columns where I would only have 1 for hour and 10 for mins. 1h and 10m should not be the output, instead 'column' hour should have 1, and column 'min' should have 10.

Comment: Okay, I edited the code. This should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working with the example data but it is not working when I am trying to access my column from the dataframe. I am trying to access my column in the following manner:          data= df3['time_taken']. After this, I follow from data['Hours']=0. Can you help me understand what I am missing? I am pretty new to Python and I am really thankful for your help.

Comment: You can't access the column with data=df3['time_taken']. You have to convert it to pandas DataFrame as shown in the example code. data = pd.DataFrame(time_taken, columns = ['time_taken'])